# How to improve self define function PCA code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I work on my little project that need to do group by PCA. Everything is fine however I look for a way to improve self defined PCA function.

Self defined function I use:

```
def pca(data):
    try:
        x = stats.zscore(data, nan_policy='omit')
        covar = np.cov(x, rowvar=False)
        eigval, eigvec = np.linalg.eig(covar)
    except Exception as e:
        return pd.Series([np.NaN]*len(data))
    else:
        return x@eigvec[:, :1]
```

I use this function to calculate 1st vector PCA as follow:

```
sam.groupby('gvkey')[['xgat', 'xgsale', 'xcap']].apply(pca)
```

Everything works fine. However, the only little issue is that there are three columns output. 1st is the `gvkey`, the 2nd is `empty`, and the 3rd is `0`.

[image]

**What I want:** improve my self defined function so that the output has no 2nd index column. In general, the result should be similar to using `groupby['col'].transform('mean')`

I do not want work around solution like using `reset_index()` as: `sam.groupby('gvkey')[['xgat', 'xgsale', 'xcap']].apply(pca).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`group_keys=False`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to remove the group key:

```
from scipy.linalg import LinAlgError

def pca(data):
    try:
        x = stats.zscore(data, nan_policy='omit')
        covar = np.cov(x, rowvar=False)
        eigval, eigvec = np.linalg.eig(covar)
    except LinAlgError:
        pass
    else:
        return x@eigvec[:, :1]

sam.groupby('gvkey', group_keys=False)[['xgat', 'xgsale', 'xcap']].apply(pca)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't realize it is that simple.